# Pandas - Display all columns when printing data (Dataframe of 4 columns)

Tags: pandas

I am trying to print output of a Dataframe. It has 4 columns but I see only 3 columns get printed in the same line whereas the fourth column gets printed in the next line. Is there anyway I can have all of these 4 columns printed in the same line

I am using the below to display all columns

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: There is `MultiIndex` ? Can you add data sample to question?

Comment: Also is possible add code, maybe is possible prevent it.

Comment: Hey @jezrael I managed to fix it by doing the below `pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)` . Thanks for reaching out..

Comment: Or use `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: I suppose `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`  wraps the columns according to the terminal size or whatever you are displaying in. Have you tried using the normal way `print(dataframe)`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by doing

`pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)`